# Fetching data from an api and manipulating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a quote generator, and I'm having a weird problem while passing the data provided from the api to my state, can someone help me with that? (I don't know why, but when I click the button to generate a quote the browser throws the error: '_this2.setState is not a function') Here are the two components used on the App:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import QuoteComponent from "./QuoteComponent";

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   qouteData: ""
 };
}

fetchData() {
 fetch("https://api.quotable.io/quotes")
   .then(res => {
     return res.json();
   })
   .then(data => {
     this.setState({
       quoteData: data
     });
   });
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.fetchData();
}

render() {
 const { qouteData } = this.state;

 return (
   <div className="App">
     <QuoteComponent
       quote={this.state.qouteData.content}
       author={qouteData.author}
       handleClick={this.fetchData}
     />
   </div>
 );
}
}

export default App;
```

Quote Component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function QuoteComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="flex">
          <div id="quote">
            <h2>{props.quote}</h2>
          </div>
          <div id="quote-a">
            <h4>{props.author}</h4>
          </div>
          <div id="button">
            <button onClick={props.handleClick}>New Quote</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default QuoteComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetchData() {
 fetch("https://api.quotable.io/quotes")
   .then(res => {
     return res.json();
   })
   .then(data => {
     this.setState({
       quoteData: data
     });
   });
}
```

in this code `this` is bound to its context which is `fetchData`. And fetchData has no member `setState`.

In order to avoid `this` being bound to the function `fetchData` you can use an arrow function:

```
fetchData = () => {
 fetch("https://api.quotable.io/quotes")
   .then(res => {
     return res.json();
   })
   .then(data => {
     this.setState({
       quoteData: data
     });
   });
}
```

Here is more information about [binding `this`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56/) in react